# Create a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a loop that produces a dataframe using input from a dictionary. I'd like to insert the ending dataframe into a new dictionary, name it the group number (12345), then start the loop over adding the new dataframe into the same dictionary, only it would have the new groups name (54321):

```
frames = {}
groups = ['12345', '54321']

for x in groups:
    # Runs a bunch of calculations with the ending output being a pandas df
    frames = df.to_dict()
```

Obviously I know this is wrong, I'm just scratching my head as to where I should go from here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
frames = {}

groups = ['123', '456']
for grp in groups:
    #do some calcs to get a dataframe called 'df'
    frames[grp] = df
```